# Jumping ssh hosts without netcat

Tags: ssh, netcat

I have access to an intermediate server to which I can connect with ssh.  From there I can connect to other servers: A→B→C, where A is my laptop, B is an intermediate server accepting connections from anywhere, and C is a server accepting only internal connections (including B).  Normally, one can configure ssh an A to connect seemingly directly to C, using ProxyCommand and netcat (for example, [see this blog post](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2011/05/advanced_ssh_for_developers/)).

However, in my case, on B I only have access to a very limited set of BusyBox commands, not including netcat, and OpenSSH from 2009.  Is there an alternative way, without netcat, to jump directly from A to C?

Comment: I think it's very better than netcat if you using iptables...

Comment: What about `ssh -t B ssh C`?

Comment: For what it's worth, you can use the `ProxyCommand` trick without `netcat`, like this: `ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh -A -q -l %r -W %h:%p B' C`.  I doubt it works with an OpenSSH from 2009 though.

Comment: Thank you @lcd047 this is super helpful!

Answer (score 3):

One of possible solutions is using SSH port forwarding.

First step:

```
ssh -T -L 2222:HOST_C:22 user_at_B@HOST_B
```

Second step - open new terminal and do the following command:

```
ssh user_at_C@localhost -p 2222
```

First step makes SSH-tunnel from localhost:2222 to HOST_C:22 via HOST_B.
Option `-T` prevents pseudo-tty allocation.

After the second step you'll have SSH session directly to the HOST_C.

You can obtain additional info in `man ssh` and here (for example):
[SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding)