# user@localhost password not accepted when ssh-ing through a tunnel

Tags: ssh-tunneling

I am trying to log into a workstation through another server, following this guide https://serverfault.com/questions/53080/how-to-enable-ssh-x11-forwarding-through-additional-server

Step 1, connecting to the intermediate server and forwarding the local port went fine using this command:

```
A$ ssh -L [localPort]:C:22 B
```

And I find myself logged into the server C. However when I try to connect to server C (in a new terminal window) through the [localPort] using:

```
user@user-desktop$ ssh -X -p [localPort] localhost
```

I get the following:

```
user@localhost's password:
```

The password I use to log into my machine isn't accepted, and I'm pretty sure I haven't set any other passwords on this machine. How can I set this password?

Comment: 1. `ssh -L [localPort]:C:22 B` makes connection to `B` not `C` so you are not logged into `C` but `B`. 2. `ssh -X -p [localPort] localhost` - if you don't pass username directly `OpenSSH` uses your current username, check whether it's the same as on the remote machine.

Comment: 1. Thanks - should have looked a bit more closely at that!  2. I am user1 on A, and user2 on B and C. Do I need to have the same username for all 3, or specify     ssh -L [localPort]:user2@C:22 user2@B  ?

Comment: Does `A` mean `localhost`? If  yes, `ssh -X -p [localPort] localhost` will use `user1`. If you want to log in as `user2` you need to pass it explicitly: `ssh -X -p [localPort] user2@localhost`. You don't need to change this: `A$ ssh -L [localPort]:C:22 B`.

Comment: The question like this has been discussed yesterday:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/203161/73133

Comment: Thankyou @ArkadiuszDrabczyk using the correct user has fixed the problem. I now tunnel [localport]:user2@C:22 user2@B and it works